# How can I fix this:error CS0234 in Unity?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'CrossPlatformInput' does not exist in the namespace
'UnityStandardAssets' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

`enter code here:`

```
        using System.Collections;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using UnityEngine;
        using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;
        using UnityEngine.UI;

        public class TrumpController : MonoBehaviour
        {

             private Animation anim;

             private Rigidbody rb;

   
             void Start()
             {
               anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
               rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
             }

   
             void Update()
             {

                float x = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
                float y = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical");

   

                Vector3 movement = new Vector3(x, 0.0f, y);

        
                rb.velocity = movement * 4f;

                if (x != 0 && y != 0)
                {
                transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x, Mathf.Atan2(x, y) * 
                Mathf.Rad2Deg, transform.eulerAngles.z);
                }
 
                if (x != 0 || y != 0)
                {
                 anim.Play("walk");
                }
                else
                {
                 anim.Play("idle");
                }
             }
        }
```

So I am creating my first game in unity. I am currently working on the left to right movement and getting error:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think CrossPlatformInput is under 'UnitySampleAssets' and not under 'UnityStandardAssets'" So you need to add an assembly reference:

```
using UnitySampleAssets;
```

Comment: I don't have a package with that name, so I get an error:
"The type or namespace name 'UnitySampleAssets' could not be found ( are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
And this 'UnityStandardAssets' contains 'CrossPlatformInput' (I have already checked it). 
Maybe you know where I can download the package with 'UnitySampleAssets'?

Comment: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/asset-packs/standard-assets-for-unity-2018-4-32351

Comment: This is the package that I have connected but it does not have 'UnitySampleAssets', only 'SampleScenes' and 'StandardAssets', and only 'StandardAssets' includes 'CrossPlatformInput'

Comment: Look into the `CrossPlarformInputManager` script and check which namespace it is in ..